# Is it allowed to add and remove inapp purchases in different android app version and in iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is it allowed to add or remove inApp purchases fuctionality with new android app version and iOS app Version?

I mean suppose in version v1 inApp functionality is there, but with new release version v2 I want to remove inApp purchases functionality and I want to add inApp functionality again in some other version.
Is this possible and what is correct way to do this.

I tried to find in android documentation, but not able to figured out

Thanks